# how to find out the clients connects to the proxy server in redhat linux

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, proxy, squid

Is there any way to find out the client machines connected to the particular proxy server in redhat linux , i am using redhat linux version 6 and squid configured in it

Comment: Did you check in squd logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Squid is listening on port, let's say 3128, you can list all connected IP addresses to this port by using command like `netstat` in the server.

For example:

```
netstat -na | grep :3128
```

will display something like below:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3128            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        1      0 10.12.0.1:3128          10.12.3.60:53736        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 10.12.0.1:3128          10.12.4.24:60545        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 10.12.0.1:3128          10.12.4.13:50484        ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 10.12.0.1:3128          10.12.3.55:52669        ESTABLISHED
```

You can ignore the first line, that displays the default listening of squid service. For the rest of rows, 4th row is the local server ip and 5th row lists the remote endpoint (the clients connecting to proxy). On the 6th column you can see the tcp connection status. The `ESTABLISHED` signifies a currently active connection.

You can only list the estbalished connection with this:

```
 netstat -na | grep :3128 | grep ESTABLISHED
```

You may use the command without the `-n` option, to display hostname, instead of ip addresses.

```
netstat -a | grep :3128 | grep ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: It is working but i can not resolve the hostname

Comment: I tried that but the ip is not resolving to the hostname

Comment: Then probably it's a problem related to dns settings. Netstat uses the local dns to resolve the hostnames. Check on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to list only IP Addresses, you can use the following command:

```
$ netstat -na | grep :3128 | awk '{print $5}' |uniq
```

**It will give output like:**

> 192.168.5.1:32832
>   192.168.5.1:32797